# Python while loop not working with two conditions

Tags: python, while-loop

Im trying to make a while loop that stops when two variables are equal to 0, but when one of them reaches 0 the loop ends, and I have no clue why. This is what I have...

```py
  movement=3
  attacks=1
  while (attacks != 0) and (movement != 0):
    do = input('what to do?')
    if do == 'move':
      movement -=1
    if do =='attack':
      attacks -=1
```

I could be missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated

Comment: You're using `and` between the two conditions.  Did you mean to use `or`?

Comment: You mean "until both are 0" which means "while not (both are 0)" which translates to `while not (attacks == 0 and movement == 0)` and by DeMorgan, you can write it as `while attacks != 0 or movement != 0` if you wish. In short, replace `and` with `or`.

Comment: Since 0 is a "falsy" value, you could also simply write this as `while attacks or movement:` instead of explicitly having the `!= 0`.

Comment: Note that when you fix that, you've got a more fundamental logic problem - the user would be able to use one of the actions indefinitely, with its count going negative, as long as the other action's count remains positive.

Answer (score 0):

You had two mistakes in your code.
The first one was you did not close your quotes in your input.
The second was you used an assigning operator `=` instead of a comparison operator `=` on line `7`.
Cleaned up code.

```
movement=3
attacks=1
while (attacks != 0) and (movement != 0):
    do=input('what to do?')
    if do=='move':movement-=1
    if do=='attack':attacks-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop will continue as long as the predicate `(attacks != 0) and (movement != 0)` is true. Therefore the loop will stop once the predicate is false. The predicate is false exactly when EITHER `attacks == 0` OR `movement == 0`. This is the negation of the predicate.

If you want the loop to end ONLY when both are 0, then you're saying you want the loop to continue as long as `(attacks != 0) or (movement != 0)` as the negation of that predicate is `attacks == 0` and `movement == 0`.

To find out more, see [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code, after fixing it it seems that in a while loop with 2 conditions doesn't work, here's a working version of it:

```py
movement = 3
attacks = 1
while True:
    if attacks == 0 and movement == 0: break
    do = input('what to do?')
    if do == 'move':
        movement-=1
    if do == 'attack':
        attacks-=1
```

So you create an infinite loop and inside it you check if the `attacks` and `movement` are both equal to `0`, and if they're, then break out of the loop.